# Mysql: grouping by day and hours of day

Tags: mysql

I have a database, and I've been trying for a while, but I'm not getting the results I want. Here's a sample of what I have:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| Ammount | Date                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2015-08-25 14:07:00 |
|       1 | 2015-08-25 14:12:00 |
|       1 | 2015-08-25 15:17:00 |
|       2 | 2015-08-25 15:22:00 |
|       1 | 2015-08-25 14:27:00 |
|       6 | 2015-08-25 14:32:00 |
|       1 | 2015-08-26 14:37:00 |
|       5 | 2015-08-26 14:42:00 |
|       1 | 2015-08-26 16:47:00 |
|       2 | 2015-08-26 16:52:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

And this is my query:

```
select Ammount, Date from table;
```

What I want to do is group by the day AND the hours of each day, and sum it, pretty much like this:

```
select sum(Ammount), Date from table group by hour(day(Date));
```

Except it groups everything together.

Comment: I don't think you need to have the "day" function here...

Comment: try select sum(ammount), date ,hour(day(date)) as time from table group by date,time

Comment: @Krishnakumar I do. If I place them separtely, it groups by days (but it also groups by the same day in each month (for example, all day 1s together, which doesn't make much sense)), or hours (once again, by the same hour of different days).

Comment: try **select sum(Ammount), Date from table group by date(`Date`), hour(`Date`));** . Note that the field name Date must in Backticks. You cant see it in comments

Comment: @BerndBuffen OHHHHH!! It was that. It's embarrassing I didn't think about trying that, thank you very much!

Comment: post your desired output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Ammount), Date
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),
         MONTH(Date),
         DAY(Date),
         HOUR(Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Ammount), Date from table group by month(Date), day(Date), hour(Date);
```